# compass not detecting new ruby version

Tags: ruby, compass-sass

I have ruby v2 installed on my linux virtual machine but compass doesn't detect it and still thinks I am using ruby 1.9!

```
$ compass -v
DEPRECATION WARNING:
Sass 3.5 will no longer support Ruby 1.9.3.
Please upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0 or greater as soon as possible.

Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
```

This is the ruby version

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p384 (2014-01-12) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

This is the patch to compass and ruby:

```
$ which compass
/usr/local/bin/compass

$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

I don't know what's going on any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I have an older version of ruby that is installed inside `/usr/bin/ruby` which is called by compass instead of the new one at `/usr/local/bin/ruby`.. So I just deleted the old one and updated the ruby symlink to the new version.